# Actually i searched thoroughly for updating a <p:inputMask mask="99/99/9999"> date field using java script.but its not working

Tags: javascript, date, jsf-2, primefaces

I wanna update a date feild in a form when ever any form element is changed.Form is done with prime faces.

Date Feild(Event Date) to be updated:

```
<p:inputMask mask="99/99/9999" 
             value="#{children.eventDate}" 
             converter="#{dateConverter}" 
             id="cfc_eventdate" 
             disabled="#{editFamilyCtrl.sendFlag||editFamilyCtrl.contextCtrl.viewFromWorklist}">
    <f:attribute name="childBirthDate" 
                 value="#{children.affiliateTO.childTOs[0].dateOfBirth}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="mwpEventDateValidator" />
    <p:watermark for="cfc_eventdate"  
                 value="dd/mm/yyyy" />
</p:inputMask>
```

I am calling a js function  "on change" event:This is DOB feild

```
<p:column styleClass="borderStyle">
    <p:inputMask mask="99/99/9999" 
                 styleClass="#{(editFamilyCtrl.affiliateTOExist.dateOfBirth ne editFamilyCtrl.mutationRequestTO.mutationTOs[0].affiliateTO.dateOfBirth) and editFamilyCtrl.sendFlag ? 'updatedInput' : 'white'}"
                 value="#{editFamilyCtrl.mutationRequestTO.mutationTOs[0].affiliateTO.dateOfBirth}"
                 id="cfa_dob" 
                 disabled="#{editFamilyCtrl.sendFlag}" 
                 onchange="setEventDate(this)">
        <p:ajax event="blur" 
                update="@this" />
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        <f:validator validatorId="mwpdobValidator" />
    </p:inputMask>

    <h:outputLink disabled="#{editFamilyCtrl.sendFlag}" 
                  onclick="calDialog.show()" 
                  value="javascript:void(0)" 
                  styleClass="calStyle">
        <p:graphicImage value="../images/calendar.png" 
                        styleClass="calImg"/>
     </h:outputLink>
</p:column>
```

This is my Js function:

```
<script>
    function setEventDate(val) {      
      var obj = document.getElementById("editFamilyForm:cfa_eventdate");
      if(!((obj.value).match(/^\d+/))) {
          var today = new Date();
          var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            var today=dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yyyy;
            $("#editFamilyForm\\:cfa_eventdate").val(today);
        }
    }
</script>
```

On changing dob feild above js is getting called and it displays date(dd/mm/yyyy) in event date feild.but if we click the particular field (event date)  the updated value will get erased or if cursor is already  present in event date feild js updatation is not happening..Thanks in advance

Comment: @kamwo: please refrain from such minor updates. The post goes up to the top of the 'active topics list' because of edits. Edit things like this only if there are other edits that improve the question (the title is very wrong in many other ways)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `<p:ajax event="blur" update="@this" />` means that whenever any cursor movement occurs on `cfc_eventdate` component, it's value will be ajax-updated via a server side refresh.

Since you're changing the value of `cfc_eventdate` using purely client-side js, it's value will not be stored on the server side. As a result, if any cursor movement occurs after  `setEventDate()` function runs, the following will happen

1. Client-side value (that is displayed on the component) will be updated on the component
2. `<p:ajax/>` will trigger an ajax request to the server
3. Server will receive request and lookup the value binding for `cfc_eventdate`, which is `#{children.eventDate}`. Because JSF has not been made aware of the purely client-side update, `children.eventDate` will retain it's original server side value. It is this original value that will be sent in the ajax response to (2).

At the end of the process, whatever client-side change you made will be undone with the ajax response. The point is: If you want to ajax update a component based on another component's value, use proper ajax, not just javascript.